# Camel route to ActiveMQ destination

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to set up a basic route from File system to a JMS Destination running on ActiveMQ. My ActiveMQ server is running on localhost using default settings and has a Queue available at "**activemq/queue/TestQueue**".
So I have coded the following Java route:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost");
    context.addComponent("jms",
            JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:D:\\camel\\in").to(
                    "activemq:queue:TestQueue");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
}
```

Unfortunately the following Exception is raised:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[activemq:queue:TestQueue] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:D:\camel\in]] -> [To[activemq:queue... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: activemq://queue:TestQueue due to: 
No component found with scheme: activemq
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:945)
    . . . .
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: activemq://queue:TestQueue due to: No component found with scheme: activemq
```

I have tried with some other variations of the "to" route, such as "activemq:queue:activemq/queue/TestQueue" without success. Any idea how to make it work ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" protocol for connecting to an external ActiveMQ server. Also it's strange you don't have any error message after posting to "vm:". Have you included all slfj logging libraries in your project?

Comment: Thanks! by including slfj libraries in the classpath I've found out that the issue was the protocol. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you named the JMS component `jms`, you need to reference the queue as follows:

`"jms:queue:TestQueue"`

instead of

`"activemq:queue:TestQueue"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I have changed the JMS endpoint to jms:queue:TestQueue and the error disappeared. However from the ActiveMQ I can see no pending messages for that Queue. Is my understanding correct that files contained in the "in" route will be sent as JMS message ? (Ps tried with "jms:activemq/queue/TestQueue" as well, getting no error but no message received also)

Comment: For receiving JMS messages using Camel, use the same URI such as `from("jms:queue:TestQueue")`.

Answer (score 4):

Your are probably missing the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```